# HelloWorld App Engine Tutorial gives me error 500

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I just uploaded the HelloWorld Java tutorial to my app engine account and encountered error 500 when trying to load it.

Everything works if I connect to [the main page](http://tiwiz-test-00.appspot.com/) but if I click on Trdev (that is the tutorial), I just get this error:

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>   If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this
>   error message and the query that caused it.

I looked onto the website and found out quite a lot of solutions, even removing comments, but nothing works and I can't figure out what could be...

Can anyone help me, please?

Many thanks :)

Comment: How about posting your code here?

Comment: Did you check in the Admin Console of your GAE app? The logs might contain more information about the error than is displayed on the web.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the stacktrace in the logs on the Admin Console. This will tell you the line number where the error occurs and hopefully you can find the problem and the solution from there.

Edit:
Based on your stacktrace, it looks like you're compiling with the wrong version of Java. You need to make your classes compatible with Java 1.6, either by using the JDK version 1.6 or by setting your binary compatibility to 1.6 in javac (unfortunately this means the source needs to be compatible with 1.6 too).

```
javac -target 1.6 -source 1.6
```

In Netbeans, you set the Source/Binary Format  under the properties for the project.

In Eclipse, you set the Compliance Level under  Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Compliance Level.

Please note, you'll have to do a full clean build - deleting all your .class files and any .jar files you've created.

Comment: Sorry for the late, I had to work a lot and totally forgot about it :( By the way, this is the log
[link](http://pastebin.com/8EfMG6Dg)